# Embedding image height and width in a td or img tag

Tags: jquery, html, ajax

I have a bunch of images on the server and when the client sends up an ajax .load() request the server PHP script echoes out a table with an img tag in each td. That presents a nice table of the image thumbnails at the client.  But I'd like the server script to encode the width and height of the original image, somehow,  into each td or img tag.

I thought perhaps I could write this information into the alt or title string of the img or td element and get it back out at the client with jQuery.

Or, I think I read somewhere that you can stick *any* attributes you want into an element, but I can't find the reference now. Browsers won't respond to them but the data will be there for jQuery or JavaScript to read back out.  If that was safe I could just add an imgwidth and imgheight attribute to each img or td element. (I can't use the img tag's actual width and height attributes because the images coming down are thumbnails so they can't display at the original image's size.

Hopefully someone has some better ideas, or can verify that yes, you can stick any attributes you want into an element.

Thanks

Comment: What's wrong with using the already defined `width` and `height` attributes of `img`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [`img` element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/img) actually defines `height` and `width` attributes (which you want to set on the server side to help with rendering). As you use thumbnails to display the size, you will not be able to utilize them directly for holding this extra information.

For elements that don't define them you can use [`data-*` attributes](http://ejohn.org/blog/html-5-data-attributes/) to hold the information - you can do this on the `img` elements as well. jQuery has the [`data`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.data/) functions exactly for these.

Example:

```
<img src="..." height="100" width="100" data-actual-height="300" 
                                        data-actual-width="400" />
```

Comment: Yes! That's where I saw the arbitrary attributes: HTML5.  That will solve it nicely.  Thanks!